# How to assign an id in a dropdown menu to be able to know what was selected

Tags: grails, gsp

I have a drop down menu with three selections. Three of them directs me to the same controller and same action, however I would like each to have different id assigned to be able to do different things depending on what the id is inside the controller.

So for example if I have three selections

```
<li> choice1 </li>
<li> choice2 </li>
<li> choice3 </li>
```

and a controller action list

```
def list = {

    if(choice1 was selected)
        //do something
    else if (choice2 selected)
        //do something else
}
```

I want to be able to do different things depending on what the choice was.

Here is my GSP code

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li><g:link controller='Document' action='list'>apple</g:link></li>
    <li><g:link controller='Document' action='list'>bluberry</g:link></li>
    <li><g:link controller='Document' action='list'>strawberry</g:link></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><g:link resource="gm">v4sa</g:link></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass additional parameters to the link using the `params` attribute:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li><g:link controller='Document' action='list' params='[fruit:"apple"]'>apple</g:link></li>
    <li><g:link controller='Document' action='list' params='[fruit:"blueberry"]'>bluberry</g:link></li>      
    <li><g:link controller='Document' action='list' params='[fruit:"strawberry"]'>strawberry</g:link></li>    
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><g:link resource="gm">v4sa</g:link></li>
</ul>
```

which will add `?fruit=apple` (or whatever) to the end of the link and make the value accessible as `params.fruit` in the controller.

Comment: so in the controller it would be like :

if(params.fruit == apple)
{
    ///do something
}

correct ?

Comment: @Mozein you'd have to quote the value but yes, `if(params.fruit == "apple")`

Comment: you are the king please try to answer my new question @IanRoberts